# find the number of users voted for given product using PHP

Tags: php

I want to calculate number of users voted for given product using PHP Arrays

*output*, is in the following way.

For each node should provide 'user count', 'rating', 'percentage of rating'.

quality | rate(4 star) | number_of_users(4)
 code | rate(4 star) | number_of_users(2)
 rate | rate(4 star) | number_of_users(2)

The following is the vote array in the json format,

```
{
    "reviews": [{
        "nick_name": "vishnu",        
        "voteArr": [{
            "code": "Quality",
            "rate": "4"
        }, {
            "code": "Value",
            "rate": "4"
        }, {
            "code": "Price",
            "rate": "4"
        }]
    }, {
        "nick_name": "smerphy",
        "voteArr": [{
            "code": "Quality",
            "rate": "4"
        }, {
            "code": "Value",
            "rate": "4"
        }, {
            "code": "Price",
            "rate": "4"
        }]
    },
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: The result, i got it from magento API call

Comment: Can you add more to it? Kind of unclear.

Comment: You need to add more detail about your question

Comment: @user2629419 the json you posted not a valid json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$encoded = '{
    "reviews": [
        {
            "nick_name": "vishnu",
            "voteArr": [
                {
                    "code": "Quality",
                    "rate": "2"
                },
                {
                    "code": "Value",
                    "rate": "4"
                },
                {
                    "code": "Price",
                    "rate": "3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "nick_name": "smerphy",
            "voteArr": [
                {
                    "code": "Quality",
                    "rate": "1"
                },
                {
                    "code": "Value",
                    "rate": "4"
                },
                {
                    "code": "Price",
                    "rate": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

$ratings = json_decode($encoded);

foreach($ratings->reviews as $rating)
{   

    $avg = 0;
    foreach($rating->voteArr as $value) {
        $avg += $value->rate;
    }

    $avg = round($avg/count($rating->voteArr));

    echo $rating->nick_name." voted ".$avg."<br />";
}
```

#### Output

```
vishnu voted 3
smerphy voted 2
```

**Demo Codepad:** http://codepad.org/aOjvV0mS

Comment: thank u for u r reply, but how do i get, number of users rated(4 star) for same category(quality, value, price)

Comment: Where is category? Your json have not category index